# Why insertion operator is printing address instead of string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, std

I have simple lines of code, where I am using insertion operator `<<` to show hello world string. If I use ***a operator b*** then it should result to `a.operator(b);` I try to do same thing with insertion operator and in output I got address of string, rather than actual string.

```
std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
std::cout.operator<<("Hello world").operator<<(std::endl);
```

Output:

> Hello world
>   0120CC74

I am using Visual Studio.

Does my operator conversion has any problem?

Comment: Reproducible: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaf3b651349ebd39

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
```

use overloaded output operator for `const char*`, that is free function, not member function.

```
std::cout.operator<<("Hello world").operator<<(std::endl);
```

use overloaded output operator for `const void*`, since `const char*` is implicitly convertible to `const void*`.

You can look at [member overloads here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and [free overloads here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)

Answer (score 5):

My bet is that member function operator for `std::ostream(char*)` is not overloaded.

If you look at [ostream::operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), `void*` is best match and `char*` naturally gets converted to it, while global [operator<<(std::basic_ostream)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), has exact overloads for `char*` types, which gets picked up.

Of course, they behave differently.

Comment: Just noticed that I have managed to stray-downvote this perfectly good answer. The vote is unfortunately locked by now, so I can't undo it, but I wanted to clarify that there is nothing wrong with this answer. Sorry! :(

Comment: And I was just 30 seconds late to be 1st. So much rep gone. Oh, I'm a poor boy... No biggies =).  I think I can edit it, so you can retract your vote, not sure. But I'm fine.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say, the problem is that you are explicitly calling the member function `operator <<`, which is not overloaded for `const char*`.

To get the `const char*` overload, you need to call the free `operator <<` function, which is appropriately overloaded:

```
operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World").operator<<(std::endl);
```

Similarly, there is no free function overload of `operator <<` for writing an `std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&)`, so for `std::endl` you have to use the member function.

From this, we can see that you can not rewrite from the infix operator syntax (`std::cout << ...`) to function calling syntax (`operator << (...)`) without losing generality.

Comment: I'd like to convert the call to `std::endl` to this style as well, but I can't seem to manage it correctly. Anybody?

Comment: `endl` is actually a template function taking the stream as argument. There is a [member function overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for `ostream` that takes function pointer, which is how your existing version works.

Comment: So `endl( operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World") );` . Note that `std::` is not needed because of ADL.

Comment: Of course, yes, this is the piece I was missing: Just like calling the member function will not resolve to the free function (the mistake OP was making), calling the free function will not resolve to the member function. In fact, it is not possible to rewrite from infix operator syntax to function calling syntax without losing generality. Apparently :)